# Having trouble rendering xhtml to page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xhtml

I am trying to render xhtml from cute editor output to display rich text in my page.  I'm trying this but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
//ce_Document is my instance of cute editor
public void btn_SaveMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XhtmlTextWriter xtw = new XhtmlTextWriter(System.IO.TextWriter.Null);
    xtw.Write(ce_Document.XHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're rendering your text directly to the recycle bin (TextWriter.Null)

You should write to the output stream of the response you're generating. Try this (don't know if it compiles)

```
XhtmlTextWriter xtw = XhtmlTextWriter(new TextWriter(Response.OutputStream));
```